# Apple News: {"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED"}]}

Tags: plugins, plugin-applenews

I have tried to follow this guide: https://github.com/pixelandtonic/AppleNews

The API's and keys I provided appear to be valid as I double-checked with my iCloud News Partner account several times.

However when I follow the link inside the plugin (https://news-api.apple.com/sections/2c427e7c-fbc0-31a8-ba00-b563dad6f998) I receive the : {"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED"}]} response.

Not sure what it could be. Any advice?